# Two NextAuth project running in one localhost

Tags: session, next.js

I have a question regarding the nextauth option settings.
I currently running two project in one local pc, and both using nextauth.
if one is logged in, session/token created on chrome the other project cannot use the nextauth

here's error

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed',
  stack: 'JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed\n'
  name: 'JWEDecryptionFailed'
}
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed',
  name: 'JWEDecryptionFailed'
}
```

I am using different secrete key for each project.
And I think project A tried to decrypt the Project B's session even it is not its session.

I have to run only one project each time if I want to properly use the nextauth.
Running two projects at the same time, it generate the error.

Is there any way to create two session for each project ? or any other way to solve the problem?

Thanks.